# Rarefaction Shocks, Bethe-Zel'dovich-Thompson (BZT) Fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, shock-waves

In his 1988 book *Compressible Fluid Dynamics,* Philip Thompson (Ransselaer Polytechnic) defines the fundamental gas dynamics derivative, viz.

$$\Gamma = \frac {c^4}{2v^3} \left(\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial P^2} \right)_s = 1+\frac{\rho}{c}\left(\frac{\partial c}{\partial \rho}\right)_s  \hspace{1cm} 
$$

and posits that when this derivative is negative, certain aspects of compressible flow will reverse themselves – e.g. rarefaction shocks are thermodynamically allowed while compression shocks are not, flow in a nozzle will transition through $Mach=1$ at the widest point rather than at the throat.

It is thought that this derivative may become negative for fluids near the critical point, especially very high molecular weight fluids.  These negative-$\Gamma$ fluids would be dubbed Bethe-Zel'dovich-Thompson (BZT) fluids.

I have read a PhD dissertation by Nannan (2009) that summarizes the state of the art at the time, including outlining the parameters of an experimental facility that could investigate this; but I have never found *experimental* evidence that rarefaction shocks or similar phenomena have been observed.

Is anyone aware of experiments showing conclusive results on this question? *Or* a separate physical reason why rarefaction shocks and "inverted nozzle flow" would be impossible, even with exotic fluids?

Note: $c=$speed of sound, $P=$ pressure, $s=$entropy, $v=$ specific volume, $\rho=$density

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the existence of "rarefaction shock interactions" when the derivative of the gasdynamic quantity $\Gamma$ is negative (i.e. BZT fluid), have only been explored analytically and numerically. This [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/admissibility-region-for-rarefaction-shock-waves-in-dense-gases/74C194DF3EC5402428B61CD8BA4FFA5E), albeit slightly dated, and the references therein gives a good introduction on the admissibility conditions for rarefaction shocks. As regards experimental detection, I suspect it will be very difficult to distinguish between isentropic expansion waves, as compared to rarefaction shocks; not to mention the challenges to simulate non-equilibrium effects in order to create a BZT fluid.

Comment: Interesting point about distinguishing it in experiment.  I would think the Diverging-Converging Nozzle setup where a BZT fluid would accelerate smoothly from M<1 to M>1 might be the most straightforward experiment.